# Android Keyboard adjust size is not working in Full Screen mode

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In fullscreen mode, I have one Edittext if I start to type edit text box is not coming up, and UI Brakes.

Comment: use this instructions https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility. You should specify `windowSoftInputMode` inside the Manifest (find your activity there).